# Regex: string up to 20char long, without specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make regexp for validating string not containing
^ ; , & . < > | and having 1-20 characters. Any other Unicode characters are valid (asian letters for example).

How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? It is just a matter of creating a negated class with limiting quantifiers.

Comment: I quite suck in regexp, the latest I've tried was \w[^;,&.<>|]{1,20} , but it doesn't match asian characters, even if it is two of them(words?)

Comment: Please also let us know the environment you are working in. PHP/JavaScript...?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
^[^^;,&.<>|]{1,20}$
```

Explanation:

- `^` assert starting of the string
- `[^` start of negated character class (`[^ ]`)
- `^;,&.<>|` all the characters you dont want to match
- `]` close the negates character class
- `{1,20}` range of matches
- `$` assert ending of the string

It will match any character other than specified characters within range of 1-20.

Comment: This `[^^;,&.<>|]{1,20}` regex will find a match even in longer strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `\w[^;,&.<>|]{1,20}` contains `\w` that might not match all Unicode letters (I guess your regex flavor does not match Unicode letters with `\w`). Anyway, the `\w` only matches 1 character in your pattern.

Also, you say you need to exclude `^` but it is missing in your pattern.
When you want to validate length, you also *must* use `^`/`$` anchors to mark the beginning and end of a string.

To create a pattern for some range that does not match specific characters, you need a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) with anchors around it, and the length is set with [limiting quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

```
^[^^;,&.<>|]{1,20}$
```

Or (this version makes sure we only match at the beginning and end of the string, never a line):

```
\A[^^;,&.<>|]{1,20}\z
```

Note that inside a character class, almost all special characters do not require escaping (only some of them, none in your case). Even the `^` caret symbol.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zG5aG6/1)

Comment: Does this expression work for you or do you need further assistance?